# how to block a user for some blade unsing laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I created a small site by laravel 6, with the four blade index, create, edit, show and an authentication system, I want everyone to see the blades index and show, and the blades create and edit prohibit that if user authenticate.
**TinghirsController.php**

```
public function __construct() {
         $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function index()
    {
       $tinghirs=Tinghir::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(30);
       return view('tinghirs.index', ['tinghirs' => $tinghirs]);      
    }
    public function create()
    {
       return view('tinghirs.create');  
    }
    public function show($id){
        $tinghirs = Tinghir::where('id',$id)->firstOrfail();
         return view('tinghirs.show', ['tinghirs' => $tinghirs]);
    }
     public function edit($id) {
       $tinghir = Tinghir::find($id);
       return view('tinghirs.edit', ['tinghir' => $tinghir]);
    }
```

**Route/web.php**

```
Route::resource('tinghirs','TinghirsController');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#controller-middleware), you can specify which controller methods you want to apply a piece of middleware to. In you're case you want to apply the auth middleware to all methods except `index` and `show`.

To achieve change the middleware call in your `__constructor` method to be:

```
$this->middleware('auth')->except('index', 'show');
```

Comment: @marzouknajib Glad I could help!